# How can I get Kafka metrics at the topic level in Java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jmx

I am trying to get Kafka metrics at the topic level in Java. The [kafka Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring) show that I can get them using JMX but I am not sure how to do this.

The docs show the MBean as being 
`kafka.producer:type=producer-topic-metrics,client-id="{client-id}",topic="{topic}"` I am unsure of where to put the actual metric name that I am after, but have attempted it as such: `"kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=\"1\",topic=\"%s\",name=\"bytes-consumed-rate\""`

I am also unsure of how to actually use the bean and where to specify the kafka cluster information.

Thus far I've got this going for me... But the bean isn't actually doing anything because I dont know how to actually execute it.

```
        String metric = String.format("kafka.server:name=BytesInPerSec,topic=%s,type=BrokerTopicMetrics", topicName);
        try{
            ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName(metric);
            String s = objectName + " ^L";
            LOGGER.info(s);
        }
        catch(MalformedObjectNameException e){
            LOGGER.error("Malformed Object Exception: ", e);
        }
        return null;
```

Ideally I want to get out kafka metrics at the topic level as an object. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using something like Prometheus JMX exporter might be easier than programming this in your own code

Comment: @cricket_007 I see that JMX exporter can be used to have the metrics output to localhost. Do you know of a solution to get the metrics into an object in java?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do here, but the exporter is designed to be used in combination with Prometheus Server. E.g. https://activewizards.com/blog/kafka-monitoring-with-prometheus-telegraf-and-grafana/

Answer (score 3):

All the clients (Producer, Consumer, AdminClient) have methods called `metrics()` that exposes all the JMX metrics.

For example, for the Producer, see [`metrics()`](http://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#metrics--) that returns a Map of all existing metrics and their values.